# How can I block a referring URL to accessing my domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, cpanel

Morning all - I'm not much of a programmer so would appreciate any help here.

In Brief, I own the website "OrangeReel.co" and there is another domain, I've never heard of and never touched forwarding to it, this is "ItalianBabyShop.com".  Issue is that this second domain accesses my site then fully loads every single one of my pages systematically, from different IP addresses over the course of an hour or two, then starts over.  Firstly, does anyone know why that would happen?

I need a way to stop this - I contacted GoDaddy with whom I have my hosting accounts, and they sent me a link to a stack overflow which suggested using .htaccess files to allow specific domains? Though I need the inverse and to just block a single domain.

I'm open to any possible help or advise you can give, as well as any information on why someone would create a lowscale DOS attack on a Wall Stickers website!?

Comment: It appears that GoDaddy is hosting that website as well. Perhaps you can also contact them and report malicious, if not suspicious, activity.

Comment: Already done thanks bracketsage, was my first port of call.

Answer (score 0):

I found this with a fairly simple search on Google, unfortunately not from this site, else I'd just link to the post.

```
<Limit GET HEAD POST>
order allow,deny
deny from <Domain name you want to block>
deny from <IP address of the domain>
allow from all
</LIMIT>
```

**Source:** http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/block-domain-access-my-site-20953.html

Comment: Thanks bracketsage - the issue is they change domains, it uses about 40 domains to roll through every page.  The IP block was my first thought.  I'll give it a go without the IP though.  Cheers